# State the points on the curve where the tangent is horizontal AND vertical

Tags: calculus, tangent-line

x = t^3 - 3t

y = t^2 -3

I tried the problem and this is what I got:

Horizontal: (0,-3)

Vertical: (2,-2) and (-2,-2)

Also I'll throw this one in since I have no one to check my work:

Find the equation of a tangent line to the curve at the point t=1

x = 1+4t-t^2

y = 2-t^3

For my equation I got:

y=-3x/2 + 7

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. One may recall that

> $$
> x'(t_0)\neq 0,\quad y'(t_0)= 0
> $$

gives an *horizontal tangent* at the point $(x(t_0),y(t_0))$ and that

> $$
> y'(t_0)\neq 0,\quad x'(t_0)= 0
> $$

gives an *vertical tangent* at the point $(x(t_0),y(t_0))$.

Here one gets 
$$
x'(t_0)=3t^2-3, \quad y'(t_0)=2t.
$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I think that is what I did

Comment: @dmsc I've checked your two answers: they are correct.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=3t^{2}-3=0=>t=^{+}_{-}1$$
for $t=1$ we have 
$$x=1^{3}-3\cdot1=-2$$
$$y=1^{2}-3=-2$$
this equal to point $$(-2,-2)$$
for $t=-1$ doing the same procedure, we have the point (2,-2).
Now for the vertical:
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=2t=0=>t=0$$
for t=0, we have:
$$x=0^{3}-3\cdot0=0$$
and
$$y=0^{2}-3=-3$$
wich is the point (0,-3). Now the second question we need the slope m of the curve first, for this we have the next $m=\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$,so.
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=-3t^{2}$$
for $t=1$ we have
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=-3$$
now we calculate for $\frac{dx}{dt}$ 
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=4-2t$$ 
for t=1 we have
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=4-2=2$$ 
then the slope m are 
$$m=\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}=-\frac{3}{2}$$, now calculate point $(x(1),y(1))$
$$x(1)=1+4-1=4=>y(1)=2-1=1 =>[x(1),y(1)]=[4,1]$$
we have the slope and the point, we can calculate now finally:
$$y-1=-\frac{3}{2}(x-4)<=>y=\frac{3}{2}x+7$$
in conclution your answer are good.

Comment: sorry.I answer late again, is dificult to me write fast in LaTeX

Comment: It's ok. do you know if my second answer to the second problem is correct?

Comment: I complete the answer above, your second answer is good too